# onClick Listener Does Not Display Toast

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener, toast

I'm attempting to set and onClick listener on the items in my listView however for some reason the toast never appears when they are clicked. I'm not sure exactly what is happening in this instance but any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

### source:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cmd> {
    Activity context;
    List<Cmd> videos;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Cmd> videos) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item2, videos);

        this.context = context;
        this.videos = videos;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtSuccess;
        TextView txtCmd;
        TextView txtPrice;
    }

    public Cmd getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.success);
            holder.txtCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);

        holder.txtSuccess.setText(cmd.getVideoName());
        holder.txtCmd.setText(cmd.getCmd());
        // holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(cmd.getImageBitmap());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoURL() + "");
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your ImageView clickable and focusable

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `ViewHolder` pattern could be improved in a couple of places.  For one, you keep resetting your `onClickListener()` every time getView is called.    You should make the following changes:

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View view = null;

         if(convertView == null){
              view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);

                final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.success);
                holder.txtCmd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
                holder.txtPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    }
                 });
                view.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             view = convertView;
         }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);

            holder.txtSuccess.setText(cmd.getVideoName());
            holder.txtCmd.setText(cmd.getCmd());
            // holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(cmd.getImageBitmap());
            holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoURL() + "");

            return view;

    }
```

Also, you should make your ViewHolder inner class static.

```
/* private view holder class */
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtSuccess;
    TextView txtCmd;
    TextView txtPrice;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to implement touch instead of click  or using `ImageButton` instead of `ImageView`

```
    holder.imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                break;

            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `ImageView` *does* support clicks. Any subview of `View` supports clicks.

Comment: but you need to put it clickable till you can make it respond for click event not by default

Comment: I tried your implementation - A toast still does not appear: http://pastebin.com/9AZA6rQG

Comment: Try my answer setClickable(true), setFocusable(true)

Comment: i try the code and it work with me , it is still doesn't work with you ??